# How to ensure that the data pulled by Prometheus is up-to-date and does not include old data before the pull interval

Tags: export, prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

> The Prometheus interval pulls data from the pushgateway. The pushgateway uses the “-persistence.file string” data persistence parameter configuration. The client sends data to the pushgateway in real time.
>
> If Prometheus pulls data within the time interval. Pushgateway did not
>   receive data from the client. What happens when Prometheus pulls data
>   from the pushgateway interval?
>
> 1. Will Prometheus pull old data outside the time interval, and then take the pull time as the time of the old data?
> 2. Prometheus will judge according to the pull time interval, pushgateway no new data during this period, and then pull the data is empty?
> 3. Still have other results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pushgateway will always serve the most recent push to it (if any) for a group. If you care about only getting very recent data then the pushgateway is not right for your use case (see https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/).

What you probably want to do is use direct instrumentation, and have Prometheus scrape your applications directly.